# Add ttcn3 syntax highlighting to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting, ttcn

I don't work with ttcn3 full-time, what I need is just basic syntax highlighting and commenting on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> added to eclipse.

After some googling I discovered Eclipse Titan, but it seems to be a full-blown IDE for ttcn3 with compiler and stuff, and I need just a plugin to eclipse.

I would like to find something like "Set syntax: ttcn3" from SublimeText, is it possible in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you go to this link:
https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.titan/downloads

you will find that you can download the Titan plugins for Eclipse (today they look like this):
**Eclipse plug-ins 6.2.0**

You may want to install them in your current Eclipse and find out if that is what you are after.

Gustavo.

Comment: it's so sad they are not available on the Eclipse Marketplace, at least I couldn't find anything for the keyword 'ttcn'

Comment: looking at the bright side of it, I'm still happy they provide them as a downloadable item, even if not present in the Eclipse Marketpace. Cheers! Gustavo.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the plugin

1.change the nature of your ttcn project for "TITAN Nature" this way:
Project popup>Properties>Project Natures>Add...>TITAN Nature.

(if this is not enough:)

2.Select Window>Preferences>TITAN Preferences>On-the-fly checker>Enable parsing of TTCN-3, ASN.1 and runtime configuration files

(You can also set perspective TITAN Editing/Titan Executing/TITAN Log Viewer)